# getElementsByTagName code optimization

Tags: python, xml, dom

I am using xml.dom.minidom for python to parse one xml. I have to fetch elements from several tags and process them. Scenario is like this :

I have two tag types  and  in the xml for which I am using getElementsByTagName method. I have to get these elements' list and process it one by one. First approach is as follows :

```
for intDirNode in dom.getElementsByTagName('IntDir'):
        path = intDirNode.childNodes[0].nodeValue
        print path
for outNode in dom.getElementsByTagName('Outputs'):
    path = outNode.childNodes[0].nodeValue
    print path
```

Now I want to combine these two lists that I get from .getElementsByTagName() into a single loop so that my work will be done in one simple loop as follows :

```
for Node in [dom.getElementsByTagName('IntDir'), dom.getElementsByTagName('Outputs')]:
    path = Node.childNodes[0].nodeValue
    print path
```

But the above code doesn't work. Is there any way to do this ?

Use case for this is that in a bigger picture I want to fetch 15 such tags from xml and its tedious to write 15 different for loops for them. I am searching for away to simplify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a list, just combine them:

```
nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName('IntDir') + dom.getElementsByTagName('Outputs')
for node in nodes:
    ...
```

In a bigger picture, you probably want to do smth like this:

```
node_names = ['IntDir', 'Outputs', ...]
nodes = []
for node_name in node_names:
    nodes += dom.getElementsByTagName(node_name)

for node in nodes:
    ...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: one question though. If I want to modify the value "Node.childNodes[0].nodeValue" and write it back to xml, will it be reflected ?
<BR>In other words, is the list nodes made with pass by reference method or pass by value ?

Comment: @tejas, yup, changes should be reflected in the dom object.